# Is memory managed on the newest iPhones?

Tags: ios7

I'm getting into iOS and coming with an Android background.  Will I have to manually allocate and remove memory in Objective C?  I'm getting conflicting answers from blog posts...  How does ARC fit in to this?

Comment: Could have done a modicum of research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is, ARC is the garbage collection system in iOS that checks for nil references and then auto deallocates the objects for you. You still have to manually allocate objects yourself.

Comment: ARC is not a garbage collection system. Cocoa uses manual memory management. ARC is a compiler feature that adds manual memory management commands to your program for you.